# SetExpressCheckout callback

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Is there any way I can be notified that someone has approved a payment through SetExpressCheckout, if they don't get redirected back to my website?

ie. After they approve the payment I would receive a callback or payment notification.

If so, how would I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will always be redirected to your site when using Express Checkout.  They have to because the payment isn't final until you call DoExpressCheckoutPayment which can't occur until after they've been redirected back to your site.  Maybe I don't understand what you're asking here..??

In any case, take a look at [IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server so you can automate post-order processing in real-time.  Again, though, no IPN would be triggered form SetExpressCheckout alone because no payment has actually been made at that point.

Comment: What I mean is, there might be some special case where the user doesn't make it back to my site for whatever reason. In those cases is there some way that I can get notification from PayPal that they've logged in and approved the payment? Then even if the user doesn't end up at my site again, my back-office processes will be able to process the payment.

Comment: You'll just have to build that into your own system.  For example, you can save the express checkout tokens you're users get in a local data table along with a status.  Update the status along the way, and then you can write a cron job to go through and try to process any payments with a token that is stuck in the middle.

Again, though, if you're not getting people back to your site using Express Checkout then you've got something wrong with your checkout in the first place, so I'd look to fix that before trying to mess with anything else.

Comment: That works, though I was expecting something a bit simpler. The users can make it through but I want to account for every possible situation. Thanks.